# FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths EF Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, entity-framework-migrations

so I have to create two relationships between Users, the one is coordinators users and professors users can write multiple comments to multiple student users. The second one is sponsor users can sponsor multiple student users and student users can be sponsored by multiple sponsor users.

This is Users entity:

```
    public class Users : IdentityUser
  {

    [Required]
    public string IdentificationCard { get; set; } = default!;

    public string FirstName { get; set; } = default!;

    public string? SecondName { get; set; } = default!;

    public string LastName { get; set; } = default!;

    public string SecondLastName { get; set; } = default!;

    public DateTime DateBirth { get; set; } = default!;

    public int Age { get; set; } = default!;

    public Gender Gender { get; set; } = default!;

    public string Photo { get; set; } = default!;

    public string? Email { get; set; } = default!;

    public States State { get; set; } = default!;

    public ContactMethods ContactMethods { get; set; } = default!;

    public string Address { get; set; } = default!;

    public Grades Grades { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Communities> Communities { get; set; } = default!;


    [InverseProperty(nameof(Sponsorships.Sponsor))]
    public ICollection<Sponsorships?>? Sponsor { get; set; } = default!;

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Sponsorships.Sponsored))]
    public ICollection<Sponsorships?>? Sponsored { get; set; } = default!;


    [InverseProperty(nameof(Comments.Publisher))]
    public ICollection<Comments?>? PublisherComments { get; set; } = default!;

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Comments.Student))]
    public ICollection<Comments?>? StudentComments { get; set; } = default!;



    public ICollection<Courses> Courses { get; set; } = default!;

    public string? RefreshToken { get; set; }

    public DateTime RefreshTokenExpiryTime { get; set; }

}
```

This is comments entity

```
public class Comments
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentsId { get; set; }

    public string PublisherId { get; set; } = default!;

    [ForeignKey("PublisherId")]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Users.PublisherComments))]
    public Users Publisher { get; set; } = default!;

    public string StudentId { get; set; } = default!;

    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Users.StudentComments))]

    public Users Student { get; set; } = default!;

    public string Comment { get; set; } = default!;

    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; } = default!;

    public States State { get; set; } = default!;

}
```

This is Sponsorship entity

```
    public class Sponsorships
{
    [Key]
    public int SponsorhipId { get; set; }

    public string SponsorId { get; set; } = default!;

    [ForeignKey("SponsorId")]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Users.Sponsor))]
    public Users Sponsor { get; set; } = default!;

    public string SponsoredId { get; set; } = default!;

    [ForeignKey("SponsoredId")]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Users.Sponsored))]
    public Users Sponsored { get; set; } = default!;

    public States State { get; set; }
}
```

This is ApplicationDBContext

```
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {

        var cascadeFKs = builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                        .SelectMany(t => t.GetForeignKeys())
                        .Where(fk => !fk.IsOwnership && fk.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        foreach (var fk in cascadeFKs)
            fk.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);


        builder.Entity<Comments>()
                    .HasOne(e => e.Student)
                    .WithMany(e => e.StudentComments)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);

        builder.Entity<Users>().HasIndex(u => u.IdentificationCard).IsUnique();

    }

    public DbSet<Users> AppUsers { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<ContactMethods> ContactMethods { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Programs> Programs { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Communities> Communities { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Courses> Courses { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Classes> Classes { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sponsorships> Sponsorships { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Comments> Comments { get; set; } = default!;
    public DbSet<Logs> Logs { get; set; } = default!;
```

Everytime I want to update the database I get this error:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Sponsorships_AspNetUsers_SponsorId' on table 'Sponsorships' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

I already put in ApplicationDBContext to disable cascade delete but the errors keeps going. Does anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `Users` logic is close to imploding. Whenever some of your business logic uses only a part of your table and other business logic uses other parts of the table, you gotta start thinking about dividing your table and storing the parts as separate tables. This is advantageous both from design and performance perspectives.

It is usually very helpful to try and create your database in a db management tool and see if it works as you intended by looking at the diagram, sometimes that is enough for you to find the answer you were looking for. Also a diagram is very helpful for people trying to answer your questions because it more clearly conveys the intent.

First, consider creating separate classes for your users:

```cs
public class Student : Users
{
    public ICollection<Sponsorships?>? Sponsor { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comments?>? StudentComments { get; set; }
}

public class Professor : Users
{
    public ICollection<Comments?>? PublisherComments { get; set; }
}

public class Sponsor : Users
{
    public ICollection<Sponsorships?>? Sponsored { get; set; }
}
```

When you add `DbSet`s for those classes, the default behavior is [table-per-hierarchy with discriminator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration) which adds a `Discriminator` column to the `Users` table to distinguish between the different types of users.
If the table logic still seems too large, then consider separating the table by using [table-per-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration) which will still keep the `Users` table and create a separate table for each derived class.